# Is the old passport with an expired US visa required?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I have a Canadian PR and am applying for a US Tourist Visa from Canada, however my old passport is back home and no courier co: is willing to send the same. Is the old passport with the US tourist Visa (Both expired) required to be shown, as it does state that as part of the requisition.

Comment: _as it does state that as part of the requisition_ I thought this answered your question

Comment: _'no courier co: is willing to send'_ - I find this highly unlikely.

Comment: @ReddHerring it's not really surprising. See this text that's present on each Indian passport - https://ibb.co/ZTjKvwS

"This passport should not be sent out of any country by post. This should be in the custody either of the holder or of a person authorized by the holder."

Comment: Do you have a current passport?

Comment: @nikhil: what Indian authorities write, is not what Indian authorities mean. BTW the passport is expired, so also that sentence. But if OP want to be very very safe, he could contact consulate: they could send him the passport (as they regularly do).

Answer (score 1):

I can share my experience earlier in the year. I've been working in America for the last 5 years, after my trip to India I landed in Canada as a PR and had scheduled a visa appointment for the USA.

My wife's old passport and visa were expired, my passport with the visa is current but the visa had expired. At the Calgary consulate, they asked for any passports with valid US visas and the current passport. So my wife only had to present her new passport (We had her old passport too, and we asked if they wanted to see that as well but they didn't).

Do note that this was not for a B1/B2 but for a L1 and L2 visa. If you have time for your appointment then I'd recommend writing a letter of Authorization for a friend or family member to bring back your old passport. If you don't have time then you should be able to present them with a photo/scanned copy of all the pages in your expired passport and explain to them why you couldn't get the old passport with you in person.